# JQuery Datatable filter css

Tags: jquery, datatable, filter

I have a really dumb question if you don't mind me to ask :(

the thing is that I would like to customise the filter in my datatable to the search field similar to stackoverflow's but i've been struggling so much recently so not sure if i can do it.

my datatable looks like the one from the example in the link below:
[link text](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: As an aside, you may want to mark some of your other questions as answered. This will promote community in SO and make people more willing to help you.

Comment: what you mean, when say css in header?

Comment: i didnt know i am supposed to mark them sorry. trying to find how to mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eventually how i did it was: i disabled the visibility of the datatable filter, and created a search box for the table and applied css to it. could not find a way to customise the actual searchbox of the datatable, had to do it in a short time, so made it in an ugly way :)